# Real life scenarios for advices in aop

Tags: spring, aop

what are some real life scenarios for various advices in AOP

1. Before : executes before Joinpoint execution.
   Could be useful for data validation.
2. After returning : executes when method successfully completes execution.
   could be useful for doing some formatting work of returned data, check if data is null, if null then return something else instead of null.
3. After throwing : executed when joinpoint throws an exception. Could be useful if we want to do some logging of exception.
4. After : executes no matter how the method exists. could be useful if we want to clear up some resources ?
5. Around : executed both before and after the joinpoint, could be useful if we want to do some time logging.

I would like to know some of real life scenarios to use these advices.

## update

want to know the practical usage of each advice like:
1. Before
 - I am not sure but can be used for Security

2. Around

   - its used in Spring transaction management.
3. After

   - To clear database resources.
4. After returning

   - to do some notification work.
5. After throwing

   - Logic to recover from exception, or to log exception reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of options :
1. When you want add log messages to understand what's running, without debugging or without changing code
2. Add extendable plugins everytime a function is started and closed
3. Monitor application run. How much times each function run? how many memory it consumes? how much time did it took? etc.